# I'm trying to create a minecraft server and the following error:

Tags: minecraft

I'm trying to create a minecraft server and the following error:

> E:\Documentos\Minecraft>java -Xms1G -Xmx2G -jar server.jar -o false
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough
>   space for 2097152KB object heap E:\Documentos\Minecraft>PAUSE
>   Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you give *any* more details? How can we reproduce this error, for instance?

Answer (score -1):

Your error message states
"Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap"

You don't have enough memory to run your server. Try upgrading your storage capacity.

Answer (score -1):

The computer you are running this on does not have enough memory to allocate 1 gigabyte to a process. You will need to get a computer with more RAM to run a server.

Answer (score -1):

You are using more RAM to the server that you have, in run.bat change:

> java -Xms1G -Xmx2G -jar server.jar -o false

to

> java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -jar server.jar

In recent versions "-o" don't works more.